# Circumventing Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle with Special Relativity...?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

*The Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, formulated by Werner Heisenberg, states a fundamental limitation on the **simultaneous** precision with which certain pairs of complementary observables*

So what I understand about it is, that one cannot simultaneously make a precise measurement of the momentum and the position of a particle. I understand the limitation is mainly on the simultaneous measurements. But we know (from special relativity) that **simultaneity is relative**.

That is, if two events (**say the momentum and the position measurements**) are simultaneous in my frame, they aren't so in another inertial frame that is in relative motion to my frame.

So what if I let another person (inertial observer) in the relatively moving frame make the observations that are simultaneous to me, but non-simultaneous for him/her? She/He can make accurate measurements (in principle of course) of the physical quantities as the events won't be simultaneous. Then later I can have him/her share the results with me. That way I can have both simultaneous and precise measurements of both momentum and position without any problem.

*I haven't done the mathematical analysis of the idea yet, so I am not completely certain of it.*

So, your thoughts?

Comment: It's the other way around - Quantum Mechanics circumvents Special Relativity by allowing quantum entanglement of space-like separated particles.

Comment: Before asking about the combination of SR and HUP, I think you should better understand each of them separately. Your claim is based on a double misunderstanding on both sides of the problem.

Comment: Please note that simultaneous measurement of 2 *commuting* properties is not limited by the HUP.  So the issue has nothing to with special relativity, as already noted in other comments.

Answer (score 3):

Simultaneity is relative for two events that are spatially separated.  You are asking about the simultaneous measurement of position and momentum at the *same location*.  All observers will agree that those two measurements are simultaneous,